# How to position the check box inside li element to center?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, center

I have a list of items with a `div` content and a span with check box. I want to position my check box span to center of `li` element.

```
<li class="e-list e-state-default e-list-check">
    <div class="cont-bg">
       content here varies
     </div>
 <span >
 <input class="e-lv-check e-checkbox e-js e-input" type="checkbox"/>
  </span>
</li>
```

Content is loaded dynamically so its height and width varies. I couldn't set padding for positioning. Tried on positioning using vertical-align as well. Nothing worked.

```css
.e-list.e-state-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #c8c8c8;
}
.e-list {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.cont-bg {
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.e-list .e-lv-checkdiv {
  float: right;
}
.e-list {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.e-list {
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li class="e-list e-state-default e-list-check">
    <div class="cont-bg">
      <div class="brooke">
      </div>
      <div class="listrightdiv">
        <span class="templatetext">Brooke</span>  <span class="designationstyle">HR Assistant</span>
        <div class="aboutstyle">
          Brooke provides administrative support to the HR office. Brooke provides administrative support to the HR office. Brooke provides administrative support to the HR office.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span><input class="e-lv-check e-checkbox e-js e-input" type="checkbox" tabindex="" name="null" value="true" /> </span>
  </li>
  <li class="e-list e-state-default e-list-check">
    <div class="cont-bg">
      <div class="brooke">
      </div>
      <div class="listrightdiv">
        <span class="templatetext">Brooke</span>  <span class="designationstyle">HR Assistant</span>
        <div class="aboutstyle">
          Brooke provides administrative support to the HR office. Brooke provides administrative support to the HR office. Brooke provides administrative support to the HR office.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span><input class="e-lv-check e-checkbox e-js e-input" type="checkbox" tabindex="" name="null" value="true" /> </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Why are you mixing `<div>` and `<span>`? Having both in span will give you right results right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i am a bit confused on working on this for a day probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you mixing `<div>` and `<span>`? Having both in span will give you right results right? You can use something like this:

```css
.e-list,
.e-list span {vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<li class="e-list e-state-default e-list-check">
  <span class="cont-bg">
    content here varies
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class="e-lv-check e-checkbox e-js e-input" type="checkbox"/> This is centered.
  </span>
</li>
```

If for some reason, you cannot change your `<div>` to `<span>`, use:

```css
.e-list {vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;}
.e-list div,
.e-list span {vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<li class="e-list e-state-default e-list-check">
  <div class="cont-bg">
    content here varies
  </div>
  <span>
    <input class="e-lv-check e-checkbox e-js e-input" type="checkbox"/> This is centered.
  </span>
</li>
```